# rails css bootstrap align multiple form check_boxes

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, simple-form

i'm trying to make a rails form and aligning multiple check_boxes over an image , the layout works fine when i'm using Chrome browser but when i'm using other browsers eg. Firefox Safari the check boxes are offset, this is the Chrome layout [image: Chrome layout] ,and this is the Firefox layout [image]

This is my form code

```
<div id="container-test">
<div class="pagination">

<div class="pagination bgg"> 
<%=f.check_box :var, :style => "vertical-align: -450px; margin-left: 58px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var1, :style => "vertical-align: -430px; margin-left: 4px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var2, :style => "vertical-align: -410px; margin-left: -37px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var3, :style => "vertical-align: -430px; margin-left: -35px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var4, :style => "vertical-align: -395px; margin-left: 4px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var5, :style => "vertical-align: -370px; margin-left: 4px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var6, :style => "vertical-align: -344px; margin-left: -42px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var7, :style => "vertical-align: -370px; margin-left: -34px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var8, :style => "vertical-align: -333px; margin-left: 17px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var9, :style => "vertical-align: -303px; margin-left: 10px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var10, :style => "vertical-align: -303px; margin-left: -64px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var11, :style => "vertical-align: -273px; margin-left: 4px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var12, :style => "vertical-align: -263px; margin-left: 2px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var13, :style => "vertical-align: -244px; margin-left: 5px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var14, :style => "vertical-align: -244px; margin-left: -60px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var15, :style => "vertical-align: -222px; margin-left: 4px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var16, :style => "vertical-align: -212px; margin-left: 3px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var17, :style => "vertical-align: -194px; margin-left: 4px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var18, :style => "vertical-align: -194px; margin-left: -60px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var19, :style => "vertical-align: -170px; margin-left: 4px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var20, :style => "vertical-align: -163px; margin-left: 30px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var21, :style => "vertical-align: -132px; margin-left: -22px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var22, :style => "vertical-align: -136px; margin-left: -40px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var23, :style => "vertical-align: -160px; margin-left: -14px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var24, :style => "vertical-align: -124px; margin-left: 40px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var25, :style => "vertical-align: -96px; margin-left: -2px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var26, :style => "vertical-align: -94px; margin-left: -40px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var27, :style => "vertical-align: -112px; margin-left: -30px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var28, :style => "vertical-align: -124px; margin-left: 58px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var29, :style => "vertical-align: -90px; margin-left: 8px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var30, :style => "vertical-align: -82px; margin-left: -40px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var31, :style => "vertical-align: -100px; margin-left: -36px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var32, :style => "vertical-align: -88px; margin-left: 50px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var33, :style => "vertical-align: -118px; margin-left: 6px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var34, :style => "vertical-align: -96px; margin-left: 4px" %>
<%=f.check_box :var35, :style => "vertical-align: -80px; margin-left: -36px" %>


</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: could u pls share working link.. have uadded reset styling for browser or try to give fixed width and align left to the check boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **css margin and vertical-align** properties *to align your checkboxes which is not correct way to do it* as different browsers can handle it differently( which you just encountered). Simplest solution to your problem would be to **use relative position on your image and then make your checkboxes absolutely positioned**. This will always align your checkboxes according to the image. You need to do something like:

```
#some-id-of-image{
  position: relative;
}

#checkbox-1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;  // change them accordingly
  top: 20px;   // change them accordingly
}
```

For details checkout [**`absolute positioning inside relative positioning`**](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)